# Using AWS Elastic Inference without making changes to the client code

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I have an endpoint deployed in SageMaker with a Tensorflow model, and I make calls to it using the Scala SDK like this:

```
    runtime = AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
        .build()
   ...
   val invokeEndpointResult = runtime.invokeEndpoint(request);
```

Can i use Sagemaker's Elastic Inferece with this code as it is and gain the performance enhancement of EI? 
I have tried running an endpoint with a configuration of 8 ml.m5d.xlarge instances vs a configuration with 8 ml.m5d.xlarge instances with added EI of ml.eia2.xlarge but looking at the cloud watch metrics I get the same number of invocations per minute, and the total run time (on the same input) is the same.

Comment: From my initial attempts it looks like performance is not improved and even degrades a bit.